# Определить кодировку текста

Tags: кодировка

Имеется `*.pdf` документ с текстом на кириллице. При копировании текста в `*.txt` файл он отображается некорректно. Решил разобраться, что за кодировка используется в оригинальном `*.pdf`: скопировал букву "ч" в текстовый файл, открываю его в шестнадцатеричном редакторе, где букве "ч" сопоставляется байт 68. Подскажите, где можно сверить байтовое представление буквы "ч" в различных кодировках?